# Where is the iconset command-line tool 'iconutil' located?

Tags: command-line, icons, xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard, iconutil

I have XCode 4.2 and need to submit a Mac app to App Store. I've tried all kinds of suggested methods to get the multi-resolution icons in there, so you don't need to inform me on that.

The remaining method is to use `iconutil`. I've searched in Spotlight, searched my Mac's harddisk in Finder, two later XCode `.dmg` images, `sudo find` in Terminal, and looked for paths on the web. The XCode 4.4.1 `.dmg` had `Iconutil.strings` and `Iconutil.xcspecs`, but that's as far as I've come.

Is there a package I can download to get this command or tool, so I can convert the `.iconset`? If there is a setting I can change in XCode to make it allow the old `.icns` files (before `1024x1024` and `512x512@2x`), that would be a solution that I could accept temporarily. I have OS 10.6.8.

**EDIT**
I would accept an answer that confirms whether the command is there in 10.6.8 and where it is. I would accept an answer that links to a valid `.icns` file with `512x512` and `512x512@2x` (preferably uncompressed `.png` inside) that has been approved by App Store validation recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have both Xcode 4.2 and Xcode 3.2.5 installed on Snow Leopard and iconutil is not in the system.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my question.

Comment: There seems no way of getting a iconutil command onto Snow Leopard. Certainly not one that will convert icons to meet the changed criteria of App Store.

Answer (score 5):

I have Xcode 4.5. There you must install the command-line tools separately.
Check Xcode Preferences --> Downloads --> Components. There you should find "Command Line Tools" and a download button where you can install these tools.

Then you can proceed as shown in the OS X documentation: [Optimizing for High Resolution, Provide High-Resolution Versions of All App Graphics Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: adding links to the documentation is usually helpful :) I've added it for you

Answer (score 1):

You first need to ensure you have `xcode-select` ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html)) set-up correctly; this will show you the current setting:

```
$ xcode-select -print-path
```

This needs to point to the `/.../Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` folder, so if you had `Xcode.app` installed in `/Applications` you can change that using:

```
$ xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Now if `iconutil` is packaged with Xcode (I cannot check at the moment), you should be able to run it with `xcrun` ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html)):

```
$ xcrun iconutil ...whatever...
```

Comment: This is for running the iconutil command from inside the (extracted) .dmg of another XCode version?

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson No, it's for running it in whatever Xcode version is installed (or the one you want to use from the command line if more than one is installed).

Comment: It is installed in /Applications, however it says that the path in your second command is not a directory (which it isn't?) I tried xcrun after this, but it reports (perhaps due to the xcode-select fail) "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/xcrun
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap"

Comment: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` should be a directory?  I don't understand why it wouldn't be.

Comment: Because Xcode.app is an app and can't be cd'd to? `xcode-select -switch /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` "is not a directory". (I don't know how I could get the path wrong yesterday, but Xcode.app is in /Developer/Applications/.)

Comment: This is on Snow Leopard, if that's relevant. (See the tag)

Comment: Still no luck, could it be bundled in the Icon Composer .app? And if so, how to run the command?

Comment: You have an extra `/Developer` at the front of that path; that directory doesn't exist with Xcode 4.2+.